# React StackNavigator with lifted state howto

Tags: react-native, state, stack-navigator

I work with StackNavigator for navigation between a couple of screens. In these screens i will collect user information. I would like this information to be stored in one state so each view will have the same information.
I got this working but i think it is not the correct or ideal because i keep track of 2 states. One in the starting view and one in the current view. 
Hence my question is, is it possible to work with only one state?

Here is my code:

My root class which creates the StackNavigator:

```
//@flow

import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Cart from './Cart';
import DeliveryAddress from './DeliveryAddress';
import Queue from './Queue';

export type State = {
  text: string,
  user: string,
  onChange: Function
}
const Screens = StackNavigator({
  Cart: {
    screen: Cart
  },
  Queue: {
    screen: Queue
  },
  DeliveryAddress: {
    screen: DeliveryAddress
  }
});

const AppNavigation = () => (<Screens/>);

export default class Root extends React.Component < Object,
State > {
  render() {
    return <AppNavigation/>;
  }
}
```

Here my first view the Cart:

```
// @flow

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import DeliveryAddress from './DeliveryAddress';
import type {State}
from './Root';

export default class Cart extends Component < Object,
State > {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome'
  };
  handleChange: Function;
  getState: Function;

  constructor(props : Object) {
    super(props);
    console.log("Construction Cart with state");
    console.log(this);
    console.log("props");
    console.log(this.props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      user: "Lucy",
      text: "Vul in",
      onChange: this.handleChange,
      getState: this.getState
    };
  }
  handleChange(data : Object) {
    this.setState(...data);
  }

  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (<View>
      <Text>This is your cart.</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigate('DeliveryAddress', this.state)} title="Go to delivery address"/>
    </View>);
  }
}
```

and here is my second view:

```
// @flow

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import type {NavigationScreenProp}
from 'react-navigation/src/TypeDefinition';
import type {State}
from './Root';

type NavigationType = {
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp < NavigationState >
}
type NavigationState = {
  params: {
    user: "bar"
  }
}
export default class DeliveryAddress extends Component < any,
State > {
  // Nav options can be defined as a function of the screen's props:
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation} : NavigationType) => ({title: `Delivery address of ${navigation.state.params.user}`});
  handleChange: Function;

  constructor(props : Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props.navigation.state.params;
    console.log(props.navigation.state);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(data : Object) {
    this.setState(data);
    this.state.onChange(data);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("welkom in delivery address");
    // The screen's current route is passed in to `props.navigation.state`:
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (<View>
      <Text>User name: {this.state.user}</Text>
      <TextInput style={{
          height: 40,
          borderColor: 'gray',
          borderWidth: 1
        }} onChangeText={(text) => this.handleChange({text})} value={this.state.text}/>
      <Button onPress={() => navigate('Queue', this.state)} title={this.state.text}/>
    </View>);
  }
}
```

The thing is that i need to set both states like this:

```
  handleChange(data : Object) {
    this.setState(data);
    this.state.onChange(data);
  }
```

Is this the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is a nice way to solve this: Using Redux with a Provider.
with the provider it is possible do add information to a 'context':

```
  import {Provider, connect} from "react-redux";

  return (<Provider store={store}>
    <AppNavigation/>
  </Provider>);
```

the provider will add the store to the context. Any child (and grandchild) can use this store like this:

```
    console.log("this.context");
    console.log(this.context);
    const {store} = this.context;
```

above will only work if you add this into the component:

```
Cart.contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object
}
```

here is more info:
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-passing-the-store-down-implicitly-via-context